# How to hide/show controls in UITableViewCell when it goes in/out of editing mode?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, editing

I have few custom controls (image views) added programmatically to table cell. I want to hide them when table view goes into editing mode and show them again when view gets out of editing mode.
I'm not using UITableViewCell subclasses, controls are added through tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method.

When and where should I do the hide/show?

I'm wondering is this even possible without subclassing (where I could do this in layoutSubviews)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible without subclass.

Int he subclass, override layoutSubviews method and then write the code to control the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set the hidden property on the uiimageview

Comment: Yes, I know. The question is when?
What delegate method is always called when table goes in and out of editing. I can kludge a solution for going into editing mode, but can't find proper one for going out.